# Commitar transação somente se todos os EJB's tiverem sucesso

Tags: ejb

Tenho um problema complexo, mas que pode ser exemplificado através da seguinte metáfora:

```
@Stateless
public interface ChildEJB01 {
    salvarGato(Gato g);
}

@Stateless
public interface ChildEJB01 {
    salvarCachorro(Cachorro c);
}

@Stateless
public interface ChildEJB01 {
    salvarPeriquito(Periquito p);
}
```

Esses tres EJB's são usados de forma isolada em diversos pontos de minha aplicação e funcionam bem de forma isolada tranquilamente. Mas tem um certo momento que eu preciso utilizá-los juntos, veja:

```
@Statefull
public class MasterEJB {

    @EJB
    private ChildEJB01 a;

    @EJB
    private ChildEJB02 b;

    @EJB
    private ChildEJB01 c;

    public void salvarTudo(){
        a.salvarGato();
        b.salvarCachorro();
        c.salvarPeriquito();
    }

}
```

Agora eu preciso salvar todos de uma vez só e preciso que tudo seja salvo no banco de dados somente **se todos** forem salvos corretamente [transação].

Só que eu tenho percebido que mesmo que um deles dê erro o que foi feito anteriormente é salvo mesmo assim... Como faço para criar uma transação para esse método? (Estou usando JTA (gerenciado pelo Containner)).

Meu setup: Jboss AS7

---

editando pra um novo exemplo utilizando as dicas do Ricardo

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class ChildEJB01 implements C01 {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager manager;

@WebMethod
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void persist(String a){
    Model m = new Model();
    m.setDesc(getClass().getCanonicalName());

    manager.persist(m);
}
```

}

---

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER) 
public class ChildEJB02 implements C02 {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager manager;

@WebMethod
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void persist(String a){
    Model m = new Model();
    m.setDesc(getClass().getCanonicalName());

    manager.persist(m);
}
```

}

---

```
@WebService
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MasterEJB {

@EJB
private C01 c01;

@EJB
private C02 c02;

@Resource
private SessionContext contexto;

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void persist() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        c01.persist("");
        c02.persist("");

        if (i == 2) // forcando uma exceção apos 4 inserts
            throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

}

SELECT NO BANCO ANTES DE RODAR O CODIGO:

> mysql> SELECT * FROM teste;
>   Empty set (0.00 sec)
>   mysql>

OUTPUT DO CONSOLE DURANTE A EXECUÇÃO DO CODIGO:

> 10:26:00,905 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Hibernate: insert into teste (descricao) values (?)
>
> 10:26:01,006 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Hibernate: insert into teste (descricao) values (?)
>
> 10:26:01,057 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Hibernate: insert into teste (descricao) values (?)
>
> 10:26:01,101 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Hibernate: insert into teste (descricao) values (?)
>
> 10:26:01,135 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Hibernate: insert into teste (descricao) values (?)
>
> 10:26:01,168 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Hibernate: insert into teste (descricao) values (?)
>
> 10:26:01,209 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component MasterEJB for method public void implementacoes.MasterEJB.persist(): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException

SELECT NO BANCO:

> mysql> SELECT * FROM teste;
>
> +----+---------------------------+
>
> | id | descricao                 |
>
> +----+---------------------------+
>
> |  1 | implementacoes.ChildEJB01 |
>
> |  2 | implementacoes.ChildEJB02 |
>
> |  3 | implementacoes.ChildEJB01 |
>
> |  4 | implementacoes.ChildEJB02 |
>
> |  5 | implementacoes.ChildEJB01 |
>
> |  6 | implementacoes.ChildEJB02 |
>
> +----+---------------------------+
>
> 6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

===

Resumindo.. o rollback continua sem funcionar :(

== +1 edit:

agora utilizando um UNICO EJB (sem utilizados outros EJB's injetados);

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void persist() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Model m = new Model();
        m.setDesc("KEKEKEKEKKE: " + i);
        manager.persist(m);
    }

    contexto.setRollbackOnly();
}
```

o rollback não foi feito.. ta MUITO ESTRANHO :o

---

**RESOLVIDO:**

faltava ativar as transações pro meu DATASOURCE do JBOSS.. 
era so marcar a caixinha: [x] USE JTA

Comment: O métodos `salvarGato()`, `salvarCahorro()` e `salvarPeriquito()`, já estão em contexto transacional? Se sim, qual o contexto de cada uma (REQUIRED, REQUIRES_NEW...)?

Comment: o que seria estar em contexto transacional? os metodos estao todos marcados com REQUIRED

Comment: Contexto transacional (ou propagação de transação) é a forma que o container deve tratar as transações. Por exemplo, se você marcar um método como transacional e especificar que a propagação dessa transação é `REQUIRED` por exemplo, indica que se esse método for chamado de um outro método **sem ser transacional** ele criará uma nova transação. Caso o método que chama já estiver em contexto transacional, então o método chamado usará a transação aberta no método anterior.

Comment: Sim sim.. era o que eu esperava desse codigo.. Mas quando a exceção é lancada.. não é feito o rollback :( | olhe este codigo de teste: http://pastebin.com/ySMMSUwV

Comment: Veja minha resposta e veja se bate com o seu código. Se bater e ainda houver a exceção e não houver rollback, tem como editar sua pergunta e postar a exceção lançada?

Comment: pronto.. pergunta editada com um novo exemplo.. mas com o mesmo erro infelizmente.

Comment: Não é a melhor solução, mas tente fazer isso: coloque a seguinte chamada antes de lançar a RuntimeException(): `sessionContext.setRollbackOnly();` E faça o teste. Estou pesquisando o que poder ser.

Comment: Mais uma dica: anote as classes de seus EJB's com: `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)` e tente novamente.

Comment: Outra coisa estou usando a minha unidade de persistencia dessa forma: http://pastebin.com/hwn0vNrg | estou fazendo os testes que vc pediu

Comment: adicionei mais um edit.. e esse é mais estranho ainda.. de uma olhada.. e como se as transações nao funcionassem..

Comment: Algumas coisas a verificar: parece que o Dialect é InnoDB, mas confirme se o engine é realmente InnoDB. Se for MyISAM, as transações não vão funcionar mesmo. Segundo, tente fazer com um servlet, não um WebService, para reduzir o número de variáveis. Se nada der certo, tente injetar um @UserTransaction , e demarcar a transação manualmente. Se nem assim funcionar, então eu recomendaria dar uma olhada nos quickstarts disponíveis em jboss.org/jdf . Talvez um ou outro quickstart te dê alguma luz sobre o que está acontecendo (ou melhor, não acontecendo).

Comment: respostas encontrada \o/ | coloquei no post principal a resolução. :)

Comment: Legal que conseguiu resolver seu problema! Parabéns! Editei minha resposta para englobar sua solução também. Abs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos lá! Isso vai requerer um pouco de conhecimento em transações e propagação das mesmas. Além de habilitar o uso do JTA no persistence.xml.

## Alterando o persistence.xml

Para habilitar as transações via **[JTA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jta/index.html)**, deve-se especificar em qual *datasource* a transação irá ocorrer, da seguinte maneira:

```
<jta-data-source>java:/meuDatasource</jta-data-source>
```

## Anotando os EJB's

Agora, precisamos anotar os métodos dos EJB's filhos para suportar a propagação `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED`. Isso quer dizer que:

> **TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED:** Se já houver uma transação em andamento, então essa mesma transação será usada. Se não houver nenhum transação em andamento, então uma nova será criada.

Vamos aos códigos:

**ChildEJB1**

```
@Stateless
public class ChildEJB1 {

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void salvarPiriquito() {
        //codigo
    }
}
```

**ChildEJB2**

```
@Stateless
public class ChildEJB2 {

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void salvarGato() {
        // codigo
    }
}
```

**ChildEJB3**:

```
@Stateless
public class ChildEJB3 {

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void salvarCachorro() {
        //codigo
    }
}
```

E finalmente, o **MasterEJB**:

```
@Stateful
public class MasterEJB {

    private ChildEJB1 ejb1;
    private ChildEJB2 ejb2;
    private ChildEJB3 ejb3;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void salvarTudo() {
        this.ejb1.salvarPiriquito();
        this.ejb2.salvarGato();
        this.ejb3.salvarCachorro();
    }
}
```

Veja que no MasterEJB eu usei outro tipo de propagação de transação (`TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW`). O que esse tipo de propagação nos diz:

> **TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW:** Essa propagação obrigatoriamente cria uma nova transação a partir de um contexto sem nenhuma transação. Se já houver uma transação em andamento, então um erro será gerado.

## E o que todo esse código postado significa?

Significa que quando você chamar isoladamente os métodos dos EJB's "filhos", uma nova transação será criada e os objetos serão salvos. Estou partindo do pressuposto que quando esses métodos são chamados "isoladamente", **não tenha nenhuma transação aberta previamente.**

Quando os métodos dos EJB's filhos forem chamados pelo método `salvarTudo()`, veja que no próprio método `salvarTudo()` a transação já é aberta e essa transação **se propaga para os métodos dos EJB's filho**. Se a transação falhar em qualquer método dos EJB's filhos, então o *rollback* será feito e nenhum objeto ficará persistido de nenhum EJB filho.